# How to find next element in a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am using a `vector` in a C++ program and I would like to find the next element inside the `vector` when looping through it, similar to how it would work with a linked list creating a next node. I am planning to use this loop to check the current element in a `vector` against the next element to see if they are the same.

Comment: What code do you have?

Answer (score 5):

```
for (auto i = v.begin(); i < v.end()-1; ++i) {
    if (i[0] == i[1]) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use this loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size()-1; ++i) {
    if (v[i] == v[i+1] { // if current element equals next element 
     ... // do something
    }
}
```

Simple

Comment: Using this for loop I am trying to implement an if statement that will check each time if the i+1 has nothing else to check. I am having errors doing this. At the moment I have a check for if(v[i+1]!=NULL) but it is throwing errors that there is no match for operator != . Is this something that is possible to check doing it with this loop?

Comment: you don't have to do that check, it's redundant. The if statement is completely safe, it will never go out of the bounds of the container since the counter is only going up to v.size() - 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).

```
// Example copied from page linked to.
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 3, 1, 4 };
    auto it = v.begin();
    auto nx = std::next(it, 2);
    std::cout << *it << ' ' << *nx << '\n';
}
// Output:
// 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you use the vector as a circular list (that is, you consider the first element as the "next" of the last element), you can use the modulo operator against the length of the vector.

For example:

```
int getNext(std::vector<int> vect, size_t i) {
    return vect[ (i+1) % v.size() ];
}
```

This solution is useful if you need to select the next element in a "round robin" way, especially out of a loop.